# Can't get value of textbox when inside formview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, formview

I am trying to get the value of a textbox that is in an asp.net formview using jquery but have not had much luck.

Value I am trying to get is here:

```
<label class="labelWidth120" for="txtPhysicalAddrLine1">
Address Line 1:</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtPhysicalAddrLine1" CssClass="alphanumeric address" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("primaryAddress1") %>' MaxLength="50" OnTextChanged="ValueChanged" TabIndex="1"/>
```

jQuery I am using to try and get at it is:

```
var a = $('<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>').val();
alert(a);
```

I am not getting any js error,"a" is not null and the alert box is empty.  Where am I going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are forgetting the # in your jquery selector... if I had a dollar for everytime I've done that... ;-)

```
var a = $('#<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>').val();
alert(a);
```

Comment: when I add the #, I get an error in js.  I have seen several post that don't use the # in this case so I assumed it must be allowed

Comment: try writing this line and tell me what it outputs:  alert('<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>')

Comment: the '#" in a jquery selector as you have it written tells it to look for an element with an ID of whatever follows the #.  Leaving it out is looking for something entirely different.

Comment: The output from: `alert('<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>')` is <%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>

Comment: adding the # so it looks like `alert('#<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>')` results in output of #<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>

Comment: The error I get if I add the # to my original jQuery so it reads: `var a = $('#<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>').val();
alert(a);` results in a js error of "Uncaught error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtPhysicalAddrLine1").ClientID %>"

Comment: Where does this javascript function live?  This kind of call will not work if the javascript you are running is in an external file.  Move the javascript to the actual page you are calling it from.

Comment: You sir are my hero!  I am pretty new to javascript and did not know that some calls don't work when in an external file.  It is working now.  THANK YOU

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. Normally you can call JavaScript functions in another library but not when you're embedding asp.nee variables, they will only work on the aspx page you're on!

Comment: An alternative is call that function from this page and pass the asp.net variable as a parameter